# Error : Xdebug connection failed for remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I received follow log file messages using Xdebug and PHP debug for remote debugging with

- Client (Windows 8.1, Chrome Browser)
- Server (Linux CentOS 7, PHP 7.2.32, Apache 2.4.6, Xdebug - 2.9.6).

Trying so many options, but cannot solve this problem.

```
[20273] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[20273] W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[20273] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[20273] Log closed at 2020-10-25 05:35:27
```

[image: Php Info Header]

[image: Php Info Header]

[[image: Php Info 3]

I would appreciate that anyone help me.

Comment: Your Xdebug log shows that it tries to connect to VSCode on `127.0.0.1:9003`. 1) Do you actually have VSCode installed in the same OS / the same computer as your PHP? 2) If it's another computer / OS (e.g. virtual machine/remote server etc) ensure that TCP port 9003 is opened/VSCode is allowed in Firewall. If server is somewhere on internet -- make sure that your router (outer firewall) allows incoming connections on that port and forwards it to your PC where VSCode is running.

Comment: **P.S.** Just in case: how Xdebug works (communication stage): https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication . ALSO: https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: In case it could be relevant, there was firewall blocking port 9003 when I was having trouble.